# beforeShowDay() jquery datepicker, limit days not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code, which I wanted to limit the options to only selected days by clinic.

http://jsfiddle.net/pypbc/10/

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        var day = date.getDay();
        var clinic = $("#AppointmentClinicId").val();

        console.log("day:" + day);
        console.log("selected clinic:" + clinic);

        if (clinic == 1) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 1), ""];
        }

        if (clinic == 2) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 2), ""];
        }

        if (clinic == 3) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 3), ""];
        }

        if (clinic == 4) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 4), ""];
        }

        if (clinic == 5) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 5), ""];
        }

        if (clinic == 6) {
            return [(date.getDay() == 6), ""];
        }

        /*if (clinic == 0) {
            return [true, ""];
        }*/

        //return [true,''];
    }
}).val();
```

However, it always display a 0 clinic which always return false. If you remove beforeShowDay, it works. I know about "return [true,''];", it works if I have only that. But, could not figure out why it does not select the clinic properly to show the dates allowed.

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

The function you are trying to use is not `beforeShowDay` but `onBeforeShowDay`

Comment: I truly believe it is beforeShowDay.

Comment: I've tested it and it works with onBeforeShowDay.. before voting down you should test it!